# How to show a shortcode product title to text om description tab

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, shortcode

How to show the product title to text on the description tab?
**for example**
I have a text on the description tab:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. **[shortcode_title_product]** Vestibulum iaculis massa nec velit commodo lobortis. Quisque diam lacus, tincidunt vitae eros porta, sagittis rhoncus est. Quisque sed justo a **[shortcode_title_product]** erat lobortis gravida. Suspendisse nibh neque, hendrerit vel nisi at, ultrices adipiscing justo. Nunc ullamcorper molestie felis at pharetra.

I want to display a shortcode product title anywhere I want like the above example, please help me. Thanks

I have tried many tutorials with no success

Answer (score 0):

```
add_shortcode('shortcode_title_product', 'shortcode_title_product_fn');

function shortcode_title_product_fn($atts) {

    $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
        'pid' => '',
            ), $atts, 'shortcode_title_product'
    );
    if (isset($atts['pid'])) {
        $product = wc_get_product($atts['pid']);
        if (is_object($product)) {
            return $product->get_name();
        }
    }
}
```

Add the code snippet into your active theme `functions.php` and add the shortcode where you want. `[shortcode_title_product pid="7173"]`. Change the product id (pid)

Comment: thanks, but the above code can auto get the title of the product or not? instead of having to enter the product id manually. please help me